# Parallel calls to dbcontext in .NET Core EF core

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, asp.net-core, task-parallel-library, ef-core-3.0

Project uses:

- SQL Server
- .NET Core 3
- EF core

In my project, I have millions of data/records I need to make parallel read request in an API from 4 different tables.
`DBContext` has a scoped lifetime, as it is recommended. I need to make parallel calls to `DBContext`, but when I try it says the second instance has started when one is already in use (Since the lifetime is scoped).

- I tried using `AsNoTracking()` for those particular queries but still same error.
- I cannot use transient Lifetime.
- Project uses repository pattern, cannot use new `DBcontext` instance in controllers.

  ```
  public MemberRepository(
      IMemberEntityMappingHelper memberEntityMappingHelper,
      IMapperExtension mapper,
      ProjectDBContext context)
      : base(context, mapper)
  {
      _memberEntityMappingHelper = memberEntityMappingHelper;
  }
      public List<MemberSummaryModel> GetMembers(int foreignKeyId)
  {
      List<MemberEntity> members = _context.Members
                                                                      .Include(x => x.Sample)
                                                                      .Where(x =>
                                                                        x.SampleForeignkeyId == foreignKeyId
                                                                        && x.IsDeleted == false)
                                                                      .ToList();

      return _memberEntityMappingHelper.EntityToSummaryModelList(members);
  }
  ```

Parallel calls -

```
Parallel.Invoke(() =>
{
// Read from table 1
}, 
() => 
{
// Read from table 2
});
```

I need to optimize my code to make response time better.

1. Is there any way I can run parallel queries (only read)?
2. `DbContext` is not thread-safe, one instance cannot update/create entries to one instance, but why I cannot make parallel read queries?
3. How much time is it expected to get 30,000 rows at a time(when I am using all the indexes)? How can I reduce it, for me, it takes 2 min to load data?

Comment: If your DbContext instanced are Scoped and you don't share them between threads, you should not see this error.  Can you post a simplified repro that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I see this error when I make parallel read request, dbcontext is shared at that time.

Comment: Do you have `MultipleActiveResultSets` enabled in your connection string?

Comment: I tried MultipleActiveResultSets enabling still same error - One or more errors occurred. (A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> DbContext is not thread-safe, one instance cannot update/create entries to one instance, 
>   but why I cannot make parallel read queries?

Because DbContext is not Tthread safe. PERIOD. Not "update/create" - AT ALL. Much of it runs down that there is no suppose for parallel SQL statements on one DbConnection at the end, and MARS does not change that - it allows overlapping query results, not overlapping query execution.

> How much time is it expected to get 30,000 rows at a time(when I am using all the 
>   indexes)?

Indices: Less relevant than size of objects and your network connection. Last time I dd that it was half a million entries in half a second - but those entries where small AND the network conenction was VERY fast.

> Is there any way I can run parallel queries (only read)?

Yes, Multiple db connections, multiple DbContexts.